# Реализация метода push в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Ребята, как можно **реализовать свой метод массивов Push**?

Например, у нас есть массив чисел, `var numArr = [10,20,30,40]`, к этому массиву я хочу добавить в конец еще 2 числа: 50 и 60, я сделаю это с помощью `push`, `numArr.push(50,60)`.

Но как я могу реализовать метод `push`, то есть будет `function myPush ()`, которая и будет выполнять все те же действия что и метод массивов `Push`.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. Приведите пример результата, которого хотите добиться.

Comment: Например, у нас есть массив чисел, var numArr = [10,20,30,40], к этому массиву я хочу добавить в конец еще 2 числа: 50 и 60, я сделаю это с помощью push, numArr.push(50,60). Но как я могу реализовать метод push, то есть будет function myPush (), которая и будет выполнять все те же действия что и метод массивов Push.

Answer (score 1):

Если одно число добавляете, то так:

```js
    var numArr = [10,20,30,40];
    var val1 = 30; // Число, которое добавляете.

    function myPush(arr, val) {
        var lenght = arr.length;
        arr[lenght] = val;
        return arr;
    }

    console.log(myPush(numArr,val1));
```

```js
    var numArr = [10,20,30,40];
    var val1 = 30; // Число, которое добавляете.

    function myPush(arr, val) {
        var lenght = arr.length;
        arr[lenght] = val;
        return arr;
    }

    var Nums = [1,2,3]; // Если добавляете несколько чисел.

    Nums.forEach(function (c) { // То проходим массив добавления
        myPush(numArr,c) // Вызываем нашу функцию MyPush
    });

    console.log(numArr);
```